# How to make monochrome emoji to colorful emoji in Android Studio editor Windows?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, emoji, jetbrains-ide

I can't figure out how to display colorful emoji in Android Studio IDE.

All emoji color is green and I'm not able to figure out which emoji is which...

[image: All emoji color is green and I'm not able to figure out which emoji is which...]

Comment: What is your OS? The support for emoji on Windows has been [added](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2917/Support-color-emoji-on-Windows#focus=Comments-27-6231560.0-0) just recently. You need to download the JDK, where this support has been added and set IT to run under this JDK: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/switching-boot-jdk.html

Comment: Also make sure the Font you are using support the emoji. Try [this font](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JBR-2917/Support-color-emoji-on-Windows#focus=Comments-27-5795443.0-0) as fallback font in IDE (Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | Font | **Fallback font**).